# CPLEX 12.8 requires -ldl in the linker flags

Tags: c++, codeblocks, cplex, compiler-flags

My question is about [this issue](https://github.com/ampl/mp/issues/114) with CPLEX 12.8 (unlike the previous versions, it requires `-ldl` linker flag). I use Code Blocks (for C++) in Ubuntu 16.04 and already tried to add `-ldl` flag in the Linker setting (Other linker options). Unfortunately it does not work. I also cannot find the file "FindCplex.cmake" as mentioned in the [link](https://github.com/ampl/mp/issues/114). I appreciate it if you could help me fix this in Code Blocks.

Here is the build log just in case you need it:

> /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio128/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/libcplex.a(mkl_memory_patched.o):
>   In function `mkl_serv_set_memory_limit': mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x5a9):
>   undefined reference to`dlopen' mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x5ca): undefined
>   reference to `dlsym' mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x618): undefined reference
>   to`dlsym' mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x62e): undefined reference to `dlsym'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x644): undefined reference to`dlsym'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x739): undefined reference to `dlerror'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x78c): undefined reference to`dlopen'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x840): undefined reference to `dlopen'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x856): undefined reference to`dlerror'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x91a): undefined reference to `dlopen'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x922): undefined reference to`dlerror'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x937): undefined reference to `dlsym'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x95a): undefined reference to`dlopen'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x962): undefined reference to `dlerror'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x972): undefined reference to`dlsym'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x98d): undefined reference to `dlerror'
>   /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio128/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/libcplex.a(mkl_memory_patched.o):
>   In function`mkl_serv_allocate': mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x1897):
>   undefined reference to `dlopen' mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x18b8): undefined
>   reference to`dlsym' mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x1906): undefined reference
>   to `dlsym' mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x191c): undefined reference to`dlsym'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x1932): undefined reference to `dlsym'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x1a27): undefined reference to`dlerror'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x1a7a): undefined reference to `dlopen'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x1b2e): undefined reference to`dlopen'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x1b44): undefined reference to `dlerror'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x1c07): undefined reference to`dlopen'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x1c0f): undefined reference to `dlerror'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x1c24): undefined reference to`dlsym'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x1c47): undefined reference to `dlopen'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x1c4f): undefined reference to`dlerror'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x1c5f): undefined reference to `dlsym'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x1c7a): undefined reference to`dlerror'
>   /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio128/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/libcplex.a(mkl_memory_patched.o):
>   In function `mkl_serv_malloc': mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x2296): undefined
>   reference to`dlopen' mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x22b7): undefined reference
>   to `dlsym' mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x2305): undefined reference to`dlsym'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x231b): undefined reference to `dlsym'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x2331): undefined reference to`dlsym'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x2426): undefined reference to `dlerror'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x2479): undefined reference to`dlopen'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x252b): undefined reference to `dlopen'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x2541): undefined reference to`dlerror'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x2604): undefined reference to `dlopen'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x260c): undefined reference to`dlerror'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x2621): undefined reference to `dlsym'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x2644): undefined reference to`dlopen'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x264c): undefined reference to `dlerror'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x265c): undefined reference to`dlsym'
>   mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x2677): undefined reference to `dlerror'
>   /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio128/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/libcplex.a(mkl_memory_patched.o):
>   In function`mkl_serv_deallocate': mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x3825):
>   undefined reference to `dlopen' mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x3846): undefined
>   reference to`dlsym' Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 3
>   second(s)) 50 error(s), 15 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))

Comment: Please clear your question?

Comment: @VedPrakash Sorry Ved not sure if I understand your point. What should I make clearer? When I want to build the project I see those errors in the build log. I think I need to impose `-ldl` flag but I don't know why it does not work after I add this flag.

Comment: The build log is crucially incomplete. You've posted the errors but not the g++ linkage command that is causing them.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I finally found a solution here:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=ea08c6b2-560a-4b09-a0c1-faf8050a0165&ps=25

Comment: From your build log it's pretty clear that you were not actually configuring the linker options with `-ldl` correctly.